# update to global variable's member not reflecting in global variable

Tags: go

First of all, I am new to Go, so I guess it is obvious to me there is some proper way of doing what I am trying to achieve here.

The issue I am having is that the following code will not print "blah" when I run test(). Instead if prints a nil, even if main() was executed first. How come updating of a Global variable's member property does not get reflected on itself at a different function ?

```
var GlobalMe SomeType

func main() {
    for _,member := range GlobalMe.Members {
        member.SomeProperty = "blah"
    }
    test()
}

func test() {
    for _,member := range GlobalMe.Members {
        fmt.Println("value:", member.SomeProperty)
    }
}
```

Comment: The for loop is copying the item from `GlobalMe.Members`. Instead, do for `i := range GlobalMe.Members` and update `GlobalMe.Members[i]` (or take a pointer, `member := &GlobalMe.Members[i]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have:

```
type SomeMemberType struct {
  SomeProperty string
}

type SomeType struct {
  Members []SomeMemberType
}

var GlobalMe SomeType
```

Simply change `SomeType` to:

```
type SomeType struct {
  Members []*SomeMemberType
}
```

People often find this unintuitive, but it usually makes sense when you deal
with more basic types:

```
xs := []int{1,2,3}
for _, x := range xs {
  x = 4
}
// xs is still {1,2,3}
```

This actually doesn't compile, but if it did `xs` wouldn't change. If you wanted 
to modify the original you'd have to do:

```
xs := []int{1,2,3}
for i := range xs {
  xs[i] = 4
}
// xs is now {4,4,4}
```

This behavior is common in most programming languages. Go is just a little more explicit about it by doing the same thing for structs. (So if you want java-like behavior use pointers)